# How can I view original javscript library source code in VS Code and not the typescript version?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I just started to learn Express JS and I am someone who learns the library by clicking "Go to definition" of IDE's and tracing each method/function.

But when I click on "**Go to definition**" of javascript files, Visual Studio Code takes me to the **index.d.ts** file which is the typescript version. This is no help to me as this doesn't help me understand the underlying architecture of libraries.

How can I view the original library source code from VS Code? If not, is there any similar feature in Github (or any other source) to click a method call that will take me to the method definition?

Thanks

Comment: `.d.ts` contains the type declaration, not "the compiled typescript version".

Comment: I am a beginner, so I have very little idea about node.js and javascript in general.

Comment: Are you clicking on "go to definition" or "go to type definition"?

Comment: @mpm I tried right clicking and selected "Go to definition" and Ctrl+Click. Both took me to the same index.d.ts file

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893661/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to the TypeScript source file instead of the type definition file in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711065/go-to-the-typescript-source-file-instead-of-the-type-definition-file-in-vs-code)

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_68.md#go-to-source-definition v1.68 is adding a `go to source definition` command.

Answer (score 2):

If your `tsconfig.json` has `"allowJs": true` and `"maxNodeModuleJsDepth"` set to a sufficiently large number, and you *uninstall* the type declarations, then clicking "Go to definition" will take you to TypeScript's best guess of the definition in the JavaScript, which may be no good for JavaScript code that was never designed to be statically analyzable (e.g., I didn't get very far with Express).  For a JavaScript package that includes type declarations directly in the package instead of having a separate `@types` package that you can uninstall, you'll have to manually copy the JavaScript source code (and not the type declarations) into a subdirectory of your project and set up the `baseUrl` and `paths` options so that TypeScript finds it.

[This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6209) is for "Go to definition" to take you to the JavaScript even when the type declarations are installed.