# Look at the source found are all index.d.ts?

Tags: typescript

In the process of using ts, I wanted to see the source code for lib.
I cannot see the corresponding implementation. What should I do?

#### Update

I was hoping to see third-party `lib` source.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52464407) what you are asking about?  If not, can you clarify the question?  A specific example of what you did and the expected and actual result can help.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Looking at the iss, it seems that the problem has not been solved.So how do you usually deal with this matter?

Comment: I manually open the implementation file and use a text search to find the element I'm looking for. :/

Comment: @MattMcCutchen That's too bad.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Thank you for your reply, which helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

run `tsc scriptname.ts`
This will compile the new JavaScript file to be `scriptname.js`.

## Update

To compile all `.ts` files in a directory, just create a `tsconfig.json` file in that directory, with these minimal options:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES6",
    "outDir": "ts-built",
    "rootDir": "src"
}
}
```

**Note:** The `outDir` is the directory to save the compiled `.js` files.

### To compile

Run `tsc -w` this will compile all `.ts` files from the `rootDir` and save them in the `outDir` directory.

Comment: But I'm targeting my entire project, not a `.ts` file

Comment: Sorry, may be I describe my purpose is not clear. I was hoping to see third-party ` lib ` source. If you practice can lead to a ` GC `, because ` node_modules ` is too big.