# How to navigate to interface's implementation in VS Code as easily as in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying Visual Studio Code for TypeScript projects at the moment. So far, I like it, but I'm having an issue with interfaces. I would like to be able to jump to interface's implementation(s) as easily as I can with WebStorm. Just a click on the green button on the left as in the picture below jumps to the implementation (or shows a list of there are multiple implemenations).

Anyone know how to do it in VSCode?

[image: Interfaces in webstrom]

Comment: `ctrl + click` works in VSC

Comment: Ctrl + Click does not do anything.

Comment: I mean implementation. In case you have multiple implementation, jetbrains/webstorm shows a drop down list of all the implementation. It is quite nice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to implementation instead of TypeScript declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893661/go-to-implementation-instead-of-typescript-declaration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VS Code does not have a specific command to find all implementations of an interface method (you could consider filing a feature request), but the "Find All References" command does give you a list that contains the implementations as well as the calls.

Comment: I am code with golang and Find All Reference always return one definition at the interface itself. Do I need to make any configuration to make this works?

Answer (score 45):

You can go to the implementation of an interface by clicking on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>. You can always read more about this in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-implementation).

- Go to Definition: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>
- Go to Definition (Alternative): <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Go to Implementation <kbd>Crl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Go to Implementation <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (MAC)

Comment: Yes, there's such a command. Unfortunately, it works pretty much the same as "Go to Definition", so I can only see type definitions but not the actual code... Wanted to inspect some library's code, but have to find the files manually :\

Comment: "Go to implementation" shortcut doesn't seem to work on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). Might have to do with system keybindings.

Comment: Confiirmed.  Ctrl + F12 does not work on linux ( debian )

Comment: @user1077915 you can use shift+F12 to look up of implements.

Comment: How to go implementation for mac Touch Bar user?

Answer (score 6):

You can use  `Goto implementations` (Ctrl-F12) or `Find all implementations`

[image: VS code snapshot]

I'm currently using Codium but this should make no difference since it is all based on extensions.

```
Version: 1.46.1
Commit: cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d
Date: 2020-06-19T10:53:55.306Z
Electron: 7.3.1
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-37-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use Regex search for your particular language. For example in PHP the syntax is like this

```
class Model implements Arrayable, ArrayAccess, Jsonable, JsonSerializable, QueueableEntity, UrlRoutable
```

So if you wanted to find all classes that implement the `Jsonable` interface, you could do this:

**Regex:**

```
implements(.*)Jsonable
```

Answer (score 0):

VS code support that. I use java, vs code support that, I think it's then same with ts, rigth click at the interface or super class, then choose "find all implements".
[image]