# How to navigate from a node_modules implementation file to its declaration file (and vice versa) in a VS Code typescript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows, visual-studio-code

This is similar to [How to navigate to interface's implementation in VS Code as easily as in WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777885/how-to-navigate-to-interfaces-implementation-in-vs-code-as-easily-as-in-webstor) but none of those answers work as described, likely because the files I'm trying to navigate reside in the node_modules directory: pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> only presents implementations/declarations within the current file.

I'm looking for a way to jump from a node_modules library's implementation directory to its declaration directory. If it's possible to jump to the line relevant to my original cursor placement, all the better, but that isn't a requirement. My goal is to streamline my current process:

#### If a node_modules declaration file is the focused tab and I want to find its implementation

1. Open the file explore window
2. Scan for the node_modules directory
3. Click to expand
4. Scan for the module name's directory
5. Click to expand
6. Scan for the `index.js` file
7. Click to open

#### If a node_modules implementation file is the focused tab and I want to find its declaration

1. Open the file explore window
2. Scan for the node_modules directory
3. Click to expand
4. Scan for the `@types` directory
5. Click to expand
6. Scan for the module name's directory
7. Click to expand*
8. Scan for the `index.d.ts` file
9. Click to open

* Occasionally I'll discover a `@types/` dir doesn't exist because the type files were bundled within the implementation package. When I realize that at this step, I perform these actions instead:

1. Click on a different editor to make the file explorer jump to a different location
2. Click back to the implementation tab I already had open to make the file explorer jump back to its directory
3. Scan for the `index.d.ts` file
4. Click to open

---

If all of this can be reduced to a shortcut, that would be great. If not, how do I reduce these steps? I'm using Windows 10.