# How to stop VS Code "Go to definition" going to type files instead of code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click the "Go to definition" context menu in a JS file, VS Code goes to the type definition when there are type files. Is there any way to make VS Code go to the code instead of going to the type files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go to implementation instead of TypeScript declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893661/go-to-implementation-instead-of-typescript-declaration)