# Can vscode "go to definition" show the actual js code in node_modules instead of the typescript version?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, node-modules

Say I want to see expressjs code, but when I click `var express = require('express')` "Go to Definition" vscode will show me the typescript version, not the actual code in `node_mudules`.

I search the related questions here, e.g. [How can I view original javscript library source code in VS Code and not the typescript version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464407/how-can-i-view-original-javscript-library-source-code-in-vs-code-and-not-the-typ) or related issues in github, e.g [Support for "Go to definition" of code located in "node_modules"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2550). But I still don't get a clue whether that can be done or not. That issue was closed in 2016 and someone said

> This is an issue with the typescript brain

What did that mean exactly ? Can that be done or not ?

------ update ------

Found it is actually duplicated as this [How can I go to the implementation of something instead of its TypeScript declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893661/go-to-implementation-instead-of-typescript-declaration)

`Go to source definition` is what I need.